# PowerShell one counter behaves differently at some part of a script

Tags: powershell

I am running a PS script to create an excel file with some text and the corresponding pictures to the text. Till now everything works as expected but when i want to choose the right column for the pictures with a counter something weird happens.

Before the if statement the counter behaves like it should, but as soon i let it output the counter inside the if statement the counter does something weird what i cannot explain.

**Part of the Script**

- pictures is an list of file names
- rows_sorted is an list of camera names

```
foreach ($picture in $pictures) {
    foreach ($row in $rows_sorted) {
        $xlcounter += 1
        Write $xlcounter -> counter looks fine
        if ($picture -match $row ) {
            $live_picture = "C:\Snapshots\pictures\$picture"
            $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($live_picture)
            $sheet | Add-ExcelImage -Image $image -Row $xlcounter -Column 4 -ResizeCell
            $image.Dispose()
            Write $xlcounter -> Weird things happen
        }
    }   
}
```

**Example output of counter outside the if statement:**
2                                                                                                                       3                                                                                                                       4                                                                                                                       5                                                                                                                       6                                                                                                                       7                                                                                                                       8                                                                                                                       9                                                                                                                       10                                                                                                                      11                                                                                                                      12                                                                                                                      13                                                                                                                      14                                                                                                                      15                                                                                                                      16                                                                                                                      17

**Example output of counter inside the if statement:**
2                                                                                                                       205                                                                                                                     408                                                                                                                     611                                                                                                                     814                                                                                                                     1017                                                                                                                    1220                                                                                                                    1423                                                                                                                    1626                                                                                                                    1829                                                                                                                    2032                                                                                                                    2235                                                                                                                    2438                                                                                                                    2641                                                                                                                    2844                                                                                                                    3047                                                                                                                    3251                                                                                                                    3454                                                                                                                    3657                                                                                                                    3860                                                                                                                    4063

I tried to rename the counter because the same name was used in a few lines before, but that did not help either.

Comment: when initializing the variable try to use `[int]` and increment the counter with `$xlcounter++`

Comment: Defnitely don't use `+=` to increment a counter - it's slow and wasteful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a (partial) list of file names as well as a (partial) list of camera names to see how a picture name matches a camera name (`$picture -match $row`). Maybe incrementing `$xlcounter` _before_  `foreach ($row in $rows_sorted)` could help?

Comment: @Scepticalist `+=` does not  cause any described problem when applied to a variable of type `[int]`…

Comment: @JosefZ Incrementing the counter before the second foreach worked. Thanks for the help and tips.